# Drag and drop div in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I try to drag and drop a div element (call it A) in a box B which is a another div. I would like to append an new div A in B each time I drop A in B.

Actually I have something like this:

```
function handleDragStart(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('application/x-moz-node', e.target);
}


function handleDrop(e) {
    //stuff
    this.append(e.dataTransfer.getData('application/x-moz-node'));
    return false;
}
```

But when I drop A in B: **[object HTMLDivElement]** is appended in B instead of A.

Could you tell me where I am wrong and is it the good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are numerous issues with `setData` and `getData` and the cross-browser compatibility. You should only rely on the dumb old `text/plain`

I would advise you to just pass the `id` of the div A and then:

```
function handleDragStart(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.id);
}

function handleDrop(e) {
    var a = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
    a = a.cloneNode(true);
    a.id = "a new id here otherwise it is duplicated id";
    this.appendChild(a);

    e.preventDefault();
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: Could you also give the set part please?

Comment: Edited. This assumes that you have an `id` attribute on div A of course

Comment: I do not have id yet but I will add some

Comment: Interesting: when I drop A in B firefox try to open www.The_id_of_A.com => do not forget to add  e.preventDefault();

Answer (score -1):

Drag and drop is a very common feature. It is when you "grab" an object and drag it to a different location.

In HTML5, drag and drop is part of the standard: Any element can be draggable.
You can refer below link:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop